# How to call a VBA-macro in another MS Word document?

Tags: vba, ms-word

in MS Excel I have been distributing a xls-file that contains a macro. From the users "random" current open workbook I have successfully been calling this macro by telling Word in which file to look for it. Like this, when the user clicks a button on the ribbon:

C:\\"'MyExcelFileWithTheMacro.xls'!MyMacroName"

**Can I do the same in MS Word?**
That is, to call a macro in a Word-file located in any given folder from an instance of Word that has not opened that file?

I have tried, of course, but Word keeps saying it can't find the macro.

The reason I want to do it this way is that it is makes for easy distribution and updating of the macro. Next up is signing the macro. I hope it can be done when doing things this way, but not sure.

Comment: Here you go https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/177760

Comment: The file containing the macro must be opened in Excel and Word VBA must have a connection to the Excel application in order to run the macro, as described in the link posted by Sorceri.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough in my qestion, and will edit it now. I ment: Is it possible to call a macro in a Word-file located in any given folder from an instance of Word that has not opened that file?

Comment: The link in the initial comment is broken.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to call and run a macro in *any* Office application if the file that contains the macro is not loaded in the application interface.

That being said, if you place the macro in a *.dotm template and have the user put the template in the STARTUP folder used by the Word application, then Word will load the template as an "Add-in". And in that case you should be able to access the macro.

Or, if you don't want it in the Startup folder and you have code that automates the Word.Application, anyway, then that code can *load* the *.dotm as an "Addin", which should make the macro available (and remove it when you're done with it). Research `Application.Addins.Load` and `Addin.Installed` in the Word language reference as well as on-line for examples.

Comment: Although I'm on my own computer and no one else uses it, Windows says I don't have permission to save anything in the designated STARTUP folder.